# How to make href work in jquery-bootgrid basic plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

Am using bootgrid-basic to show my data,

```
<table id="grid-basic"
    class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none">
    <thead>
        <th data-column-id="aa">aa</th>
        <th data-column-id="ss"  data-order="desc">ss</th>
        <th data-column-id="dd">dd</th>
        <th data-column-id="ff">ff</th>
        <th data-column-id="aaa">aaa</th>
        <th data-column-id="aaaaa" >aaaAa</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($alldata as $data)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$data->aa}}</td>
            <td><a href="#">{{$data->ss}}</a></td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>{{$data->dd}}</td>
            <td>{{$data->ff}}</td>
            <td><a href="#">ASSSsdf</a></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and initialized `$("#grid-basic").bootgrid();` in script.

Everything is working fine like search,data ordering ,pagination but those links doesnt see to work.

If i use formatter links work and remaining doesnt work.

```
$("#grid-basic").bootgrid(
formatters: {
              "action": function (column, row)
              {
                  return '<a href=\"/model/' + row.actions + '"\>' +row.actions+ '</a>' ;
              }});
```

A jsfiddle link here : http://jsfiddle.net/6xpyxbcg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a parentheses missing in your JS, it should be `bootgrid({` and you need to add `data-formatter="link"` to the `th` tag of the column you wish to use the formatter on (i.e. the link column).

**HTML**

```
 <th data-column-id="link" data-formatter="link" >Received</th>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function()
{
  $("#grid-basic").bootgrid({

    formatters: {
        "link": function(column, row)
        {
            return "<a href=\"" + row.link + "\">" + row.link + "</a>";
        }
    }
  }
  )
});
```

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj8fmfr3/7/)

P.S. trying using the built in snippet next time, as there is a one click button that allows you to copy the code to the answer section and amend it accordingly.

Comment: if u see the fiidle i shared http://jsfiddle.net/6xpyxbcg/ , there is a search box, number of records per page  functionality.

But ur fiddle  doest show that.
I tried this before.